# Visual Studio 2017 error Cannot open "X" for writing - access to path is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm sorry I cannot seem to fix this error:

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS2012  Cannot open
>   'C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe'
>   for writing -- 'Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe'
>   is
>   denied.'  WindowsFormsApp1    C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\CSC 1   Active

I suppose it has something to do with the file being read only? I tried changing it and it reverts to read only, I tried closing and reopening VS, I tried running it as an administrator, I changed the assembly name and default namespace and now it won't even run the debugger

I'm new to C#, I used to do Java and never had an error like this one, sorry if it's something very simple. By the way I'm using Windows 10 with Bitdefender installed

Comment: This error typically happens if you program is running while you try to rebuild it. Exit the program before a rebuild.

Comment: I might've changed something cause I did exit the program, and it doesn't let me rebuild it gives me the same error

Comment: Any MSBuild processes hanging around? Kill those

Comment: I even restarted the pc, I don't see any MSBuild process open, Any idea why it won't even start the debugger? Like before I went into publish settings it ran the debugger, now it tells me that there's a build error gives me the same error as above, and tells me to open the previous build.

Comment: To explain: the build creates the `.exe`, and if it can't create the `.exe` then it will also not start the debugger (because the problem is considered a *Build Failure*). The only fix is to find the cause of the `.exe` being not writable...

Comment: I've just made a new application tried debug start and it actually executed, Not sure what's going on

Comment: It's not normal for sure. But for a desperate workaround, You can start a VS, and attach the debugger on the running process of the exe.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem and fixed it with deleting `obj` directory.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs because the dll file is open some where, suppose you try to delete the dll file from obj folder then also message appears that "The file is open in another program."

In my case, I close all VS instance and copy the root folder and paste it into another folder then open my solution in VS it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this issue on a few occasions.  It seems the best way to fix this is to close down everything and restart your computer.  It seems there is a lock on a file within the bin folder of the project and the best/only way I found so far to get around this issue is to restart your computer.

Comment: I found the issue back then, it was an antivirus/windows defender automatically detecting my application as a virus and deleting certain parts of it (I believe I had a method that saved a text file into the pc when clicking a button)

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this restoring the .exe from the Quarantine zone in the Avira Antivirus, restarting the computer and turning off the real time protection in Avira, after these steps I could compile the project again.

Comment: Incredibly late reply to my own thread but yes, at that time I believe I was making a cryptocurrency calculator (winform), I believe that Windows Defender automatically flagged it as a virus, and that was what was happening.