# .net build exception - permission exception with .exe creation. Other files created without problem in same location

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-10

When I build a .NET solution for a Windows Application, it gives an exception

> Cannot open \theProject\obj\debug\net471\theApplication.exe for
> writing -- 'Access to the path
> 'theProject\obj\debug\net471\theApplication.exe is denied.'

It writes a lot of other files to the same location without issue. Any ideas of what the problem is?

.net 4.7.1, VS 2019 Pro, Windows 10

edit:

I have tried running VS in admin mode.

edit 2:

An exe file is created without issue in a different solution on the same machine.

Comment: Are you sure `theApplication` isn't already running outside of VS, manually started, or ex. as a service? Else you can try [this app](https://lockhunter.com/) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53192966/2983568).

Comment: @evilmandarine The file wasn't created at all. It doesn't exist.

Comment: How about [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35353300/2983568)? User also posted on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62a9dc7e-d743-491a-9ec7-cad183b063f3/error-bc2012-cant-open-for-writing-access-to-the-path-is-denied?forum=visualstudiogeneral); said file did not exist, and tried an extensive list of actions until he found the answer.

Comment: I'd already tried deleting the obj folder and doing clean and rebuild. BitDefender is mentioned in one of the threads you referenced. I see that is installed so maybe that is the issue. I don't think I have the ability to create exclusions to test this though.

Comment: Yeah it is bitdefender. It has quarantined the exe.

Comment: @evilmandarine If you add an answer with a link to the thread mentioning bitdefender I can mark it as the answer and close the thread.

Comment: I just looked for it and actually you found the solution buried in a comment somewhere there; I didn't do much. In this situation I think it is better if you also post the answer for your specific case and mark it as accepted, but thank you for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that BitDefender was quarantining the exe immediately upon its creation. I have requested that an exclusion is added.

This was mentioned in a comment on this thread, which I was directed to by evilmandarine: [Visual Studio 2015 can't open project.exe for writing. Access to path denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353300/visual-studio-2015-cant-open-project-exe-for-writing-access-to-path-denied)

Edit: The exception was added and the file is no longer being added to quarantine, but it still is giving the same exception. Tried restoring the items from quarantine and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: You should not be developing viruses ;-)